# Can I create extra pages programmatically when a page is created from a certain component?

Tags: java, adobe, overriding, aem, custom-component

Say I have a certain component called ArticlePage.

Can I define or override some sort of save method on ArticlePage so that whenever a page is created from a particular template for ArticlePage I can execute code that automatically creates multiple other instances of that template (or another ArticlePage template)?

Comment: This is confusing. Is ArticlePage component or template or a page ? What is the usecase here ?

Comment: @Abhishek The basic idea is to automatically create several duplicates of a page when the first page is created. I want to pass each duplicate some data so that they all end up as unique variations of the original page. The use case is for the author to be able to create content once and have it published in several different places automatically. Does that make sense?

Comment: This is an interesting usecase. JCR listener, as mentioned by Sandeep will fully automate it but it is too level in my opinion. Another way is to create a custom workflow which can perform the page replication task and ask the author to subject that page thru that workflow. Additionally, AEM's `PageManager` API provides ways to copy pages and is much richer than JCR APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `EventHandler`-interface to track events on Pages and Assets. As Abhishek said the `EventListener` interface is a low level interface that should not be used for AEM-based manipulations.

See the API docs at:
https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/index.html?org/osgi/service/event/EventHandler.html